# ASP.NET How to separate a C# variable from the rest of HTML without a space

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, variables

I have this simple code in ASP.NET:

```
@for (i=0;i<5;i++){
   var day = GetDayNameAsString().Remove(2);

   <input type="checkbox" id="@day_CB"/>
   <label for="@day_CB">@day</label>
}
```

What I want to happen is that the checkbox ids are "Mo_CB", "Tu_CB", etc.

But I can't do that, because `_CB` counts as part of the variable. So intellisense thinks it has to look for the variable `day_CB`. Is there a way of telling VS when the variable ends, while keeping the underscore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it: If I actively call `ToString()`, VS knows where the variable ends:

```
<label for="@day.ToString()_CB">@day</label>
```

Comment: updated after testing: you can also do something like this, by using single quotes to start and wrap the c# code in parentheses: `<label for='@(day + "_CB")'>@day</label>`